# $m$ balls into $n$ already occupied urns

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

Assume that there are n urns, $k\in\{1,...,n-1\}$ of which have already at least one ball. $m$ new balls will be thrown into urns. Each of the $m$ balls is thrown randomly and uniformly into $n$ urns. That is, each ball goes into each urn with probability $1/n$.

What is the probability that there are then exactly $r$ non-empty urns among those urns which were not occupied at first?

( assume that both balls and urns are distinguishable)

Comment: To get $\{$ and $\}$, use `\{` and `\}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the incremental/differential version of the coupon-collector problem. The first state reached has $n-k$ empty urns (=coupons not yet collected), and the question concerns the probability of the followup state with $n-k-r$ empty urns after collecting $m$ more coupons. The formulas of [Birthday Probability Problem New Version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789300) figure out the probability of reaching the first state after buying $M$ coupons and the probability of reaching the followup state after buying $M+m$ coupons. The result, if $M$ is known, is a conditional probability which is the ratio of the these two probabilities.  Here, $M$ is not known, but one can still factorize the algorithm as follows:
The first of the $m$ balls (=coupouns bought in addition)
enters one of the $k$ partially filled urns with probability $k/n$, one of the empty urns with probability $p_1(k,n)=(n-k)/n$. The new state is the same as the old one (with respect to the filling status) with probability $k/n$, and a state with $n-k-1$ empty urns with probability $p_1(k,n)$. Recursively, the states with $n-k-r-1$ empty urns originate from states with $n-k-r$ empty urns with probability $(n-k-r)/n$ and stay at states with $n-k-r-1$ empty urns with probability $(k+r+1)/n$ after throwing one more ball. This gives the recurrence $p_{m+1}(k,n,r) = (n-k-r) p_m(k,n,r)/n +(n-k-r-1) p_m(k,n,r+1)$, rooted at $p_0(k,n,0)=1$.