# Birthday Probability Problem New Version

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

My friends and I were talking about a different version of the Birthday Problem in probability (with the original being the probability that at least two people in a group share a birthday).

We were curious how to calculate the probability that a group of size $n$ celebrates a birthday on every day of the year. We decided to ignore leap years (though feel to free to include them) and the fact that there are more births on some days than others in real life. Obviously, the probability is $0$ when $n < 365$.

So we could know when we got to the right answer, I simulated the situation with python and got the following graph: [I simulated each group size from 365 to 5000, 100 times, and plotted the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Qvw.png). It's possible that I made an error doing this because I made it pretty quickly, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: The "phase transition"  i.e. around what $n$ it starts to become very likely that there is a birthday every day is known as the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem You can start from there.

Comment: Considering leap years makes the problem much more complex because the coupon-collector problem assumes equal probabilities which we would not have anymore. So, it is a good idea to ignore them for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I am not sure whether I remember it right, but if so ,  Stirling numbers can be used for the probabilities in the coupon-collector problem. Maybe, you google "Stirling numbers" , it might be helpful.

Comment: If $n$ people are randomly assigned to $d=365$ days, the probablity that $d_i$ days get $i$ people is
$$
P(n;d_0d_1d_2\cdots) = \frac{d!}{d^n} \frac{n!}{(0!)^{d_0}d_0!(1!)^{d_1}d_1!(2!)^{d_2}d_2!...}
$$
with $\sum_{i} d_i=d$, $\sum_{i} id_i=n$, $d_i\ge 0$, $i\ge 0$. The sum over all sets is
$$
\sum_{\sum_{i} d_i=d; \sum_{i} id_i=n} P(n;d_0d_1d_2...) = 1.
$$
$d_0$ are the days w/o birthday. The question asks for the probability
$$
\sum_{\sum_i d_i=d; \sum_i id_i=n,d_0=0} P(n;d_0d_1d_2\cdots) 
$$
The Stirling numbers count how many different compositions fulfill the 2 sum conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_m(d,n)$ denote the probability that in a year of $d$ days
collecting $n$ people at random (with homogeneously distributed birthdays)
$m$ days  are not a birthday of any of the $n$.
Analog to the Coupon collector's problem (mentioned above) the probability of covering all $d=365$ days with at least
one birthday given $n$ people is one minus the probability that exactly $m=1$ or exactly $m=2$ or exactly $m=3$... or exactly $m=354$ days are no birthdays.
Because these are exclusive events, the probabilities are additive:
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{d-1} P_m(d,n)= 1;
$$
$$
P_0(d,n)= 1- (P_1(d,n) + P_2(d,n) + \cdots)
= 1- \sum_{m=1}^{d-1}P_m(d,n)
$$
The probability of $m$ days not covered: first settle the $m$ days to be January 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc,
as if days were labelled, so the days without birthday are a clump
in the initial days of the year.
The probability
that the first $m$ days are no birthdays is that the first person's birthday
is not in that initial interval, $(d-m)/d$, that the second person's
is also not in the interval, the same $(d-m)/d$ etc.
So the probability that no person's birthday is in some fixed collection
of $m$ days  is the product, $\bar P_m^f(d,n) = (1-m/d)^n$.
(The upper  index f stands for the fixed selection of days of the year).
To compute the probability that this is *exactly* the interval without birthdays one needs
(principle of inclusion-exclusion) to ensure that at least one birthday is on the first day
and every later days after that interval, which recursively winds back to
the Coupon collector's problem with $d-m$ days:
$$
P_m^f(d,n) = \bar P_m^f(d,n) P_0(d-m,n)
$$
Unfixing
these $m$ days and allowing them to be distributed anywhere over the year has $\binom{d}{m}$ choices, which gives
$$
P_m(d,n)
= \binom{d}{m}P_m^f
= \binom{d}{m}(1-m/d)^n P_0(d-m,n)
$$
with $P_0(d,n)=0$ for $n<d$.
Solving this leads to the following table for $d=365$, first column $n$ and second column probability $P_0(d,n)$:

```
400 0.177129e-116
500 0.9082668e-69
700 0.3620669e-31
900 0.79234644e-16
1100 0.2109789e-8
1300 0.00001568479825
1500 0.001978283189
1700 0.02907534714
1900 0.1322813307
2100 0.3131637654
2200 0.4145930895
2250 0.4644648251
2280 0.4936574101
2285 0.4984567378
2286 0.4994141713
2287 0.5003707839
2289 0.5022815295
2290 0.5032356540
2291 0.5041889405
2300 0.5127301303
2500 0.6804990922
2700 0.8008971010
```

This matches the graph obtained by the Monte Carlo simulation. The fact that one needs 2287 people to get a probability >0.5 is already known: see the entry 365 in Sloane's https://oeis.org/A073593 .

This was computed with the Maple program (the parameter in the penultimate line varying)

```
Pbarmf := proc(m,d,n)
    option remember;
    (1-m/d)^n ;
end proc:
Pmf := proc(m,d,n)
    option remember;
    Pbarmf(m,d,n) *Coupcoll(d-m,n) ;
end proc:
Pm := proc(m,d,n)
    option remember;
    binomial(d,m)*Pmf(m,d,n) ;
end proc:
Coupcoll := proc(d,n)
    option remember ;
    if n< d then
        return 0 ;
    end if;
    pr := add(Pm(m,d,n),m=1..d-1) ;
    print("inv P d=",d,"n=",n,pr,evalf(pr) ) ;
    1-pr ;
end proc:
# example for d=365, n=400
Coupcoll(365,400) :
evalf(%) ;
```